# Data represented in objects

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

**Object-Oriented design**

I have a database storage with many different entries but each entry has potentially a different "object_type" (where the different attributes are stored in the database). For each "object_type" I have an own python class - see the simplified code example below. Typically I need to instantiate thousands of subclass objects in each request, hence the `DataObject.get_instances()` allows me to do that at once at as it minimizes database access time, but this causes some problems with my OOP design, so I have two questions/problems:

**1.** How to let to superclass know about its subclasses as hard coding does not seem very elegant and also typically a superclass should not know about its subclasses?

**2.** How would I outsource the subclasses in different files without creating circle import statements (as each subclass needs to import `DataObject` and `DataObject` would need to import each subclass somehow)?

data_object.py

```
import pandas as pd

# mimics Database module behaviour ==========================================
df_common = pd.DataFrame({'object_id': [1, 3, 2, 4, 5],
                          'object_type': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana',
                                          'Banana', 'LittleBanana']})
db_details = {1: {'object_type': 'Apple', 'sort': 'Jazz', 'object_id': 1},
              2: {'object_type': 'Banana', 'country': 'Brazil',
                  'object_id': 2},
              3: {'object_type': 'Apple', 'sort': 'Gala', 'object_id': 3},
              4: {'object_type': 'Banana', 'country': 'Vietnam',
                  'object_id': 4},
              5: {'object_type': 'LittleBanana', 'country': 'Vietnam',
                  'object_id': 4}}    

def db_get_details(id_list, attributes, cls_name):
    # pseudo db query function
    print('Getting attributes {} (class: {}) '.format(attributes, cls_name))
    entries = list()
    for id_ in id_list:
        entries.append(db_details[id_])

    return entries

def db_get_base_data(id_list):
    # pseudo db query function
    id_data = pd.DataFrame({'object_id': id_list})
    return id_data.merge(df_common, on='object_id', how='left')


# Classes =========================================
class MetaDataObject(type):
    sub_classes = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, d):
        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, d)
        MetaDataObject.sub_classes[cls.__name__] = cls


class DataObject(object, metaclass=MetaDataObject):
    attributes = ['object_type']

    def __init__(self, object_id, object_type):
        self.object_id = object_id
        self.object_type = object_type

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls,id_list=None):
        # returns a list of sub-class instances

        # list storage of object instances
        res = list()

        # get detailed data from database
        db_common = db_get_base_data(id_list)

        # apply group_by (via data_type)
        for object_type, tmp_df in db_common.groupby(by='object_type'):

            # get the specific object_type class
            sub_class = DataObject.sub_classes[object_type]

            # check if objects come from desired classes
            if issubclass(sub_class, cls) is False:
                raise TypeError(
                    'ID of class {}, cannot be called from {}'.format(
                        sub_class.__name__, cls.__name__))
            # get class specific data
            sub_class_data = sub_class.get_attributes(
                tmp_df['object_id'].tolist())
            # instantiate
            for entry_dict in sub_class_data:
                res.append(sub_class(**entry_dict))

        return res

    @classmethod
    def get_attributes(cls, id_list):
        # query db with cls specific attributes
        return db_get_details(id_list, cls.attributes, cls.__name__)


class Apple(DataObject):
    attributes = ['sort']

    def __init__(self, object_id, object_type, sort=None):
        super().__init__(object_id, object_type)
        self.sort = sort


class Banana(DataObject):
    attributes = ['country']

    def __init__(self, object_id, object_type, country=None):
        super().__init__(object_id, object_type)
        self.country = country


class LittleBanana(Banana):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ids = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    DataObject.get_instances(ids)
    Apple.get_instances(ids)
```

sub_object.py

```
import data_object as do
class SpecialApple(do.Apple):
    pass
```

EDIT I: I suspect I would need to split off the get_instances in another independent object where DB access is optmized and the actual instantiation takes place as the bottle neck is the database access. I was hoping to get it solved into one tree of classes but I guess this is hardly possible.

EDIT II: I have updated the example (answering implicity the **question 1**) by adding more details to show why I initalized tried to solve it with this design approach.

EDIT III: Added an explicity example if a subclass is in another file. As the meta_class approach does not solve the problem here `SpecialApple` is not part of the meta_class dict, created in data_object.py. An import of `sub_object` also does not solve the problem. Any special import which would register `SpecialApple` in the meta class?

Comment: I would definitely have another object such as `DataObjectStore` that is responsible for abstracting away the database and this `DataObjectStore` could use a `DataObjectFactory` to reconstitute an object from a db resultset or any other representation. The factory could use reflection to instantiate the right class dynamically based on the type string and set all attributes. If the attributes mappings are simple this could work. You could also check if there's a good ORM in python that could handle that.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood, but I think that your design is fundamentally broken if your super-class actually needs to 'know' which classes have been created as sub-classes - that is not how inheritance is meant to work.

Why do you think that your DataObject needs to import anything about your sub-classes ?

In a superclass, when you use `self` that is a reference to the instance, either of the superclass or the sub-class depending on which one you have actually created.

A simple example may suffice :

```
class Superclass(object):
    def process_step1(self):
       print "step 1 process1"
       return self.process_step2()
   def process_step2(self):
       print 'You shouldn't call me'
       return 0

class MyProcess(SuperClass):
    def start(self):
        self.process_step1()
    def process_step2(self):
        print "My Process - Step 2"
        return 1

>>> proc = MyProcess()
>>> proc.start()
step 1 process1
My Process - Step 2
1
```

As you can see - the SuperClass calls `self.process_step2()`, but in the example, self is an instance of `MyProcess` - so it will call `MyProcess.process_step2` - this is how inheritance is meant to work.

If you really need your Superclass to know about all of the superclasses, there are three pythonic ways to do it :

- Write a class method on your SuperClass which is called by Sub-classes so that they get regsitered - i.e. called from `__new__` or `__init__`.
- Use meta-classes so that every sub-class is 'registered' when is gets created - this will register the classes - not the instances.
- Use descriptors to identify sub-classes and 'register' them - again this will register the classes, and not the instances (I think - i have never been successful with descriptors on classes :-) ).

Also - unless a module actually needs to refer to an class by name in code, your module does not need to import anything - if you have a reference to an instance - your code can access attributes and methods of that instance without importing anything.

Finally (in general) double imports aren't 'ususally' a problem - python is 'intelligent' enough to recognise when a module has already been imported - and not do it again. This will break sometimes if you use different paths to import the same module, but often even this isn't an issue unless you are using frameworks like Django which does clever things when models are created.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'MyProcess' object has no attribute 'process1'`

Comment: @Trimax - fixed: Thank you.

Comment: thanks, I have used the metaclass approach, as the `__new__` and `__init__` does not work as it needs a first instantition to be recogonized as subclass. See the updated example.

Comment: I assume you mean the 'first definition of a subclass`, rather than the first instantiation (of an instance)

Comment: any idea how to register subclass with the meta-class approach in other files to superclass (see EDIT III) ?

Comment: You build a metaclass - which keeps a list/dict of each sub class that is created using that metaclass - it doesn't matter that it is in another file. If you are worried about circular imports - you only need to import a class definition if you are refering to a specific class by name  - you don't need to import just to access the methods/attributes of a class/instance that is passed as part of a call.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely have another object such as `DataObjectStore` that would handle the responsibility of abstracting away the database and this `DataObjectStore` could use a `DataObjectFactory` to reconstitute an object from a DB resultset or any other representation.

The factory could use reflection to instantiate the right class dynamically based on the type string and set all attributes. If the attribute mapping process is simple this could work very well.

For complex data structures I'd look into existing ORMs for Python or I'd even look into storing serialized data. Depending on your querying needs serializing data in JSON or another data-interchange format could also work very well.

Finally if you aren't limited to a relationnal DB then you could look into a [NoSQL DB](http://nosql-database.org/) could be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

**How to let to superclass know about its subclasses**

In the general case, don't. Let a third-part handle this with

```
SuperClass.__subclasses__()
```

**How would I outsource the subclasses in different files without creating circle import**

*application.py*

```
from super_class import SuperClass
from sub_class_1 import SubClass1
from sub_class_2 import SubClass2

sub_objects = []
for SubClass in SuperClass.__subclasses():
    sub_objects.append(SubClass())
```

*super_class.py*

```
SuperClass():
    pass
```

*sub_class_1.py*

```
from super_class import SuperClass

SubClass1(SuperClass):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with `SuperClass.__subclasses__()` that it only takes first level subclasses (and not subsubclasses), so I am using now  the metaclass approach to overcome the problem.